# Cannot edit particular user data with user id by form using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in YII framework. I am doing update operation using YII framework. I have controller with name `sitecontroller.php`, model `jobseekerprofile.php`, view `personal.php`.

I got the error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414`

My table is job_seeker_profile
Fields
1.id
2.user_id
3.contact_no
4.gender
5.dob
6.mstatus
7.address
8.location_id
I want to edit the data in contact_no and address  according to user_id

**Model-Jobseekerprofile.php** - rules

```
public function rules()
  {
    return array(
                array('contact_no,address','required'),
    );
 }
```

**controller-Sitecontroller.php**

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

    public function actionpersonal()
  {
    $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
    $model=Jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
                                         'select'=>'contact_no,address',"condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
                                         'limit'=>1,));
    $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id);                                  
    if(isset($_POST['Jobseekerprofile']))
      {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Jobseekerprofile'];
        if($model->save())
        {
           $this->redirect(array('profile','user_id'=>$model->user_id));
        } 
      }
    $this->render('personal',array('model' =>$model));
  }

}
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `$model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id)` is not finding anything, so `$model` is null, and that is why `$model->isAttributeRequired()` throws an error. Check your incoming params because of this and check if there a profile with such id (or maybe you should search by attributes instead of by id?).

Besides you can use

```
public function actionPersonal($id) {
    $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($id);
    //
}
```

Instead of

```
public function actionpersonal() {
    $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
    $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id);
    //
}
```

Comment: shows the error Unable to resolve the request "jobsite/error". (E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:286)

Comment: It is because you have not customised your error handler

Comment: Ok, forget about changing routes, check your incoming params first of all and is there records with such values in your database

Comment: hi,added table structure in top, please look it,i want to edit contact_no and address according to user_id

Comment: Try this: Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user_id));

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionpersonal() {
    $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
    $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id);

    if (isset($_POST['Jobseekerprofile'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Jobseekerprofile'];  //post key edited
        if ($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('profile', 'user_id' => $model->user_id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('personal', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Comment: I think you replaced these query $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
            'select' => 'contact_no,address', "condition" => "user_id=$user_id",
            'limit' => 1,));    by  $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findbyattributes(array( //edited
        'user_id'=> $user_id,
        ));

Comment: shows the error Table "job_seeker_profile" does not have a column named "0"

Comment: these line make the error $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id); error is Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414

Answer (score 0):

First Check what you are getting in $_POST 
and if all is ok then try to save like

```
  $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id);

if (isset($_POST['Jobseekerprofile'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['jobseekerprofile'];
   $model->contact_no= $_POST['Jobseekerprofile']['contact_no'];  //post key edited
   $model->address = $_POST['Jobseekerprofile']['address']; 
    if ($model->save()) {
        $this->redirect(array('profile', 'user_id' => $model->user_id));
    }
}
$this->render('personal', array('model' => $model));
```

if not work then check what model returns

```
$error=$model->getErrors();
print_r($error);
```

above code surely gives you idea why it is not saving

Comment: I had edited the controller code please look it,these code $model = Jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($user_id); makes error Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414

Comment: <li><?php echo CHtml::link('Personal details', array('site/personal', 'id'=>97)); ?><!--Personal details--></li> form these page value get to controller.I have record in table with user_id=97

Comment: can you post your model and view code i think your model rule and view has some issue